# Reading from an app.config file

Tags: c#

Given an `app.config` file, How can I read the keys and values given that those keys I am interested in will all follow a pattern I establish first. For example I do know that all the names of my keys will follow a pattern of

```
<add key="my_*_Def"  value = "someValue">
```

The thing is I want to write a program that I can give these config files to it and then my program goes and finds that pattern in that file and gives them to me for further processing.

Is there a better way for writing this other than treating it as a text file and reading it line by line?

Comment: One possibility would be to create your [custom configuration section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) and then use it in the [configuration file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228062.aspx). If you have a lot of custom configuration options, why not create your own XML structure and read/evaluate it? It could be easier and faster in this case, for example using LINQ2XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
```

to find all the keys in the app.config file. ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx))

To try in another file, you'll want to get the configuration using [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx)

So;

```
var config = ConfigrationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("foo.exe.config");
var keys = config.AppSettings.AllKeys;
```

Comment: Thanks, does it need to be config file of the same app I am running? I want a separate program that for example I can point it to a config file and this goes and analyses it...

Comment: updated the answer to show how to open a different file.

Comment: It'd have been easy enough with an Xml document (eg XmlDocument.Load(path)) but yeah, it's nice that it's built into the framework.

Comment: Reckon that deserves a green tick? :)